# Vite + Typescript combine custom types with generated types at build

Tags: typescript, build, vite

### Context

So currently I am creating a library for common Vue UI elements, Typescript type definitions, and Javascript utility files across multiple projects of mine. I've written everything using Vite and Typescript, and have gotten a nice library built save one issue. In this project, I have a set of custom types that I want to share in the library. However, I'm not sure of the best way to combine it with the existing types. My build `types` directory looks something like this:

```
-/dist/types
---| index.d.ts
---| components/ ...
---| store/      ...
---| types/
------| index.d.ts
------| CustomType1.d.ts
------| CustomType2.d.ts
        etc.
```

### Question

As you can see, my custom types are in a `dist/types/types` directory, and that `types` directory nested in a `types` directory feels wrong. Now, I could easily move things in the nested `types` directory up one directory and merge the `index.d.ts` files together things together using an external script, in my case `bash`. But this feels like I'm approaching things wrong. Is there a way to merge these two with Vite or Typescript itself? It could be better directory structure or merged into one giant config file, whatever makes most sense.

### What I've tried

I've spent a fair bit of time searching the internet for answers and haven't found a good answer to this one. I've read through the Vite build options documentation, nothing there seems to match up to what I'm looking for. I did not fully read through the Rollup configuration options, as that was extremely long and not nearly as comprehensible to me. Of course, there's always the `bash` route described above, but I'm hesitant to chose that as the answer.

To be clear, there might be an answer I missed, as I am fairly new to Vite / Typescript and could be searching using the wrong terms. Any other explanations as to a premise I am misunderstanding would be much appreciated as well.

### Config

**package build command**

```bash
vite build && vue-tsc --emitDeclarationOnly && mv dist/src dist/types && cp ./dist-package.json ./dist/package.json
```

(Partly sourced from this tutorial: https://jivancic.com/posts/build-a-component-library.html#typescript-declarations )

**vite.config.ts:**

```typescript
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [ 
        vue()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
            "%": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/css")
        },
    },
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'MotiveCommmon',
            fileName: (format) => `motive-common.${format}.js`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['vue'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**tsonfig.json**

```json
{
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "types": [],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./src/*"],
            "%/*": ["./src/assets/css/*"],
        },
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "include": [
        "stories/**/*",
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist/**/*"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true
}
```

Comment: Are those "global" types or imported into each file ?

Comment: You can use `declare global` or `unplugin-auto-import` for global ones

Comment: @Dimava they are imported into each file preferably

Comment: Can you just make you `index.d.ts` `export * from` each of them?

Comment: Actually sounds like rollup-plugin-dts , maybe that?